# Export SugarCRM Reports Setup

Tags: crm, sugarcrm

I'd like to export the actual data about a report (as opposed to the report's results). Can this be done with SugarCRM? How can I copy a report from one SugarCRM instance to another?

Answer (score 0):

Report data (i.e. results) can be exported as a PDF or CSV. However, the report configuration, i.e. the filters, display columns, etc. cannot be exported through the interface. I believe the reason for this is that every system has its own set of fields and users that might be associated.

If you look in the database, though, you'll find report configuration is stored in the table `saved_reports`. I don't see why you couldn't run something like `mysqldump mydatabase saved_reports > reports.sql` and import that (via SQL) to a clone of your system. Just be sure that you have 100% users, teams and fields duplicated in the second system or you can expect issues.

Comment: I was referring to the report definition, not the data generated by them.

Comment: Edited question and answer to better reflect what you're asking for.